# Declare type of inline object with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

As you can see I create an object inline, and I don't know how to declare the type of this object.

```
     zuite.getAfters().push({    // inline object here
        timeout: obj.opts.timeout || 11000,
        desc: obj.desc || (obj.fn ? obj.fn.name : '(unknown)'),
        fn: obj.fn,
        type: 'after/teardown',
        warningErr: new Error('SUMAN_TEMP_WARNING_ERROR')
      });
```

`zuite` and `getAfters()` have the following signatures:

```
type TestSuiteGetterFn <T> = () => Array<T>;


interface Zuite {

    injectedValues: Object,
    getInjections: Function,
    getAfters: TestSuiteGetterFn<any>,

}
```

do I need to declare the type inline? Or do I just rely on the type declared in the Zuite interface and TestSuiteGetterFn type? (In this case it's just `any` but I would updated that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new type for your object literal and change the declaration for `Zuite.getAfters`:

```
interface SomeType {
    ctx: Zuite,
    timeout: number
    // ...and so on
}

type TestSuiteGetterFn <T> = () => Array<T>;

interface Zuite {    
    injectedValues: Object,
    getInjections: Function,
    getAfters: TestSuiteGetterFn<SomeType>, // Notice `SomeType` instead of `any`
}

// Your object literal is typed as `SomeType` now
zuite.getAfters().push({
    ctx: zuite,
    timeout: obj.opts.timeout || 11000,
    // ...and so on
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to declare the type of the object. Types are only a compile-time artifact. So that means the you should use them to discover compile time errors. Trying to add a type to inline object makes no difference really, as TypeScript is [structurally typed](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

What you *should* do though, is type the `TestSuiteGetterFn`. This will in turn, give strong typing to the array. What this does is make sure that the inline object matches the structure of the type you give to the array it returns. This will allow you to catch structural errors in the object literal

e.g.

```
type TestSuiteGetterFn <T> = () => Array<T>;

interface Message {
  message: string;
}

interface Zuite {
  getAfters: TestSuiteGetterFn<Message>,
}
```

**Fail**

```
zuite.getAfters().push({
  badProperty: true
})
```

The above will cause a compile error because the structure of the object literal doesn't match the `Message` type (here is structural typing in play).

**OK**

```
zuite.getAfters().push({
  message: 'hey there'
})
```

Here the object literal matches the `Message` type structure, so no compile error.